# Primefaces datatable selects unchecked checkbox rows

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

Hi I was using JSF datatable as follows

```
    <p:dataTable id="group"
       styleClass="table table-striped table-bordered"
       rowSelectMode="checkbox"
       value="#{importIssueController.impIssueStatusArrList}"
       selection="#{importIssueController.selectedIssues}"
       paginator="true" rows="10"
       paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink}         
       {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
       rowsPerPageTemplate="2,10,15" lazy="true" var="importIssue" rowKey="#{importIssue[0]}">
       <p:column selectionMode="multiple" 
       disabledSelection="#{importIssue[6] == 'yes'}"
       style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
```

here some row checkbox are disabled on some condition and user can select rows with enabled checkboxes.
The problem I am facing here is even if checkbox is disabled and I click on the row and press submit the row is selected. Is there a way i can handle this ?
I am using Primefaces 3.5

Comment: Whats the datatype of importIssue[6]? String or a boolean?

Comment: importIssue[6] is of type String

Comment: You could catch the rowSelectEvent like this: http://www.kianworknotes.com/2014/10/how-to-disable-row-selection-in.html

Comment: Try a newer version (try!, not use in production) See if it is solved. If yes, you can check the source code to find differences or upgrade, if not, file an issue in PrimeFaces issue list (PF 3.5 is **old**).

Answer (score 1):

in your DataTable use the following

```
<p:column selectionMode="multiple"
    styleClass="#{importIssue[6] == 'yes' ? 'selectionDisabled':''}" />
```

And make changes in css

```
td.selectionDisabled .ui-chkbox{
    display: none;
   }
```

This will hide the checkbox completely for that condition. Use PF 5 instead of 3.5